# Insert Performance with Auto Incrementing Column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

If I have a table that has a PK that is an auto incrementing column and my table has one single index that only contains that column, what is the performance impact on that vs having no key/index at all?

I am curious about the impact on both MySQL and MS SQL - if there is a difference.

**Update**

Just to clarify, my table has other columns, but none of them are keys/indexes.  I am only concerned right now about insert performance.

Comment: From your title you are only talking about performance in terms of inserts?

Comment: Not really sure what the question is. What is the point of a table with nothing more than a single int column? I think in general you are asking about the performance difference between a table with a clustered index and a table without? Tables with no clustered index are known as a heap and the performance is dreadful. I am speaking about sql server. I have no knowledge of mysql but I suspect it would be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under MySQL with InnoDB if you do not specify a PK or have no UK then it will automatically create a hidden column that is very similar to an auto-increment column which is used for the clustering of the table (see [the corresponding documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html)). So no matter whether you define one explicitly or not there will be some kind of auto-incremented column with an index. So performance will not be negatively impacted in adding one explicitly (in both cases inserting will be done according to a clustering index), quite the opposite, if you query on that column, it's the fastest possible access path in MySQL.

From what I could gather about MS SQL Server it provides a non-clustered option, i.e. a way to specify a table without a PK and without organizing using any index. In that case there will be a certain overhead associated with specifying an auto increment column as a PK, as there's additional data. And depending on whether you specify clustering or not, it will have to insert data according to the index as MySQL (clustered) or can just put data at the end (non-clustered)

"[Index-Organized Tables and Clustered Indexes](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index)" goes into much more detail about that kind of stuff for various databases.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing is a way of paging the data contained within your table. Think of them like bookmarks in a phonebook labelled A-Z, you want to find someone with a name starting with 'G'. You'll find it much quicker and more efficient to use the bookmarks to jump to G then if you had to scan the whole phonebook with your eyes.

Indexing works just like this

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE]
WHERE [COLUMN1] = 'G'
```

Without an index, the SQL Engine will search the entire table and eliminate every row that doesn't meet the WHERE condition. With an index, the SQL Query Optimiser will SEEK out only the rows with the corresponding search condition. You'll likely find this notice-able on bigger tables.